# Get Substring from the String based on the matching

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having string as follows

```
srring1 = "1/1/0/A1,A2:admin-status=up,id=admin-up"
string2 = "1/1/0/A1,A2:id:admin-up,admin-status=up"
string2 = "1/1/0/A1,A2:id=admin-down:admin-status=up"
```

My Output will be as follows:

```
print(string1) = admin-up
print(string2) = admin-up
print(string3) = admin-down
```

In the string my keyword is "id" by using this substring we have to retrieve value of that substring which is "admin-up". After "id" substring it has any special character like ": or =". we have to retrieve the value after that special character.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the built-in re library for regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> strings = [ 
...     '1/1/0/A1,A2:admin-status=up,id=admin-up', 
...     '1/1/0/A1,A2:id:admin-up,admin-status=up', 
...     '1/1/0/A1,A2:id=admin-down:admin-status=up' 
... ]
>>> [re.search('id[:=]([^,:]+)',id).groups(0)[0] for id in strings if re.search('id[=:].+', id)]   
['admin-up', 'admin-up', 'admin-down']
```

This will include IDs that don't have a hyphen. The Regex breaks down like this:

`id` Means "look for the literal string ID"
`[:=]` Means "followed by either an `=` or a `:`
`(` Capture the things that follow in a capture group
`[^,:]+` Capture as many characters that are *not* `,` or `:` as you can
`)` Close the capture group.

A simpler version of the regex is used to filter out strings that don't match at all. In function form:

```
>>> def get_id(log):
...     match = re.search('id[:=]([^,:]+)',log)
...     if not match:
...             return None
...     return match.groups(0)[0]
... 
>>> get_id('1/1/0/A1,A2:admin-status=up,id=admin-up')
'admin-up'
>>> get_id('1/1/0/A1,A2:id:admin-up,admin-status=up')
'admin-up'
>>> get_id('1/1/0/A1,A2:id=admin-down:admin-status=up')
'admin-down'
>>> get_id('no id found here')
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following pattern and function to get the `group`

```
import re

string1 = "1/1/0/A1,A2:admin-status=up,id=admin-up"
string2 = "1/1/0/A1,A2:id:admin-up,admin-status=up"
string3 = "1/1/0/A1,A2:id=admin-down:admin-status=up"

regex = r'id[:=](\w+-\w+)'

string1_id = re.search(regex, string1).group(1)
string2_id = re.search(regex, string2).group(1)
string3_id = re.search(regex, string3).group(1)
```

**EDIT**
Let me provide an explanation to this solution. OP wants to extract a phrase/ word after the keyword `id` which is followed by either `:` or `=`. The regex that was chosen was `r'id[:=](\w+-\w+)'`, which essentially finds a substring within the main string that has the word `id` followed by either characters `[:=]` and extract the word that follows `(\w+-\w+)`. The brackets here indicates a `group`, which is of the interest here. The `\w+` specifies alphanumeric characters (at least 1 character) followed by a dash `-` and another word after that.

This part `re.search(regex, string1).group(1)` finds `regex` within `string1` and extract the first group `group(1)`. If there's two matches and you want to extract the second group, you can change it to `group(2)`.

```
print(string1_id)
print(string2_id)
print(string3_id)
```

Output:

```
admin-up
admin-up
admin-down
```

Comment: can you explain why you downvote my answer? it is returning what the OP is trying to do

Comment: Can not say directly why your answer was down voted, but I can say your answer does not actually show or explain how it works.

Comment: thanks for the feedback @StephenRauch, i have edited my answer and provide pretty detailed explanation and also show the results